# ng-repeat table multiple times with each 3 tables in a single line

Tags: html, angularjs, bootstrap-4

I want to repeat a table multiple times with each 3 tables in the same line.
I'm using angularjs and bootstrap. I'm not sure how it is possible to ahceive this while using ng-repeat.

table 1 | table 2 | table 3

table 4 | table 5 | ...

```
<div  ng-repeat="zone in zones">
 <div class="col-4">   
 <table>
...
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `row` class on the parent and repeat the columns. Bootstrap will automatically wrap every 3 columns because you're using `col-4`.

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-4" ng-repeat="zone in zones">   
   <table>
    ...
   </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/Z3IjLRsJXX